# create unique id in mongodb from last inserted id using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Is there a way I can find the last inserted document and the field, i.e. _id or id such that I can increment and use when inserting a new document?

The issue is that I create my own id count, but I do not store this, now I've deleted records, I cannot seem to add new records because I am attempting to use the same id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to check insertion order in MongoDB, because the database does not keep any metadata in the collections regading the documents.

If your `_id` field is generated server-side then you need to have a very good algorithm for this value in order to provide collision avoidance and uniqueness while at the same time following any sequential constraints that you might have.